# algorithms average case time complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

If an algorithm with O(n<sup>2</sup> ) average case time complexity takes 10 seconds to execute for an input size of 1000 elements, how long will it take to run when the input size is 10,000 elements?

Comment: We generally don't relate big O to exact time, but still it would take about roughly 10^5 seconds you can say ( although not  correct to do ) time= a.n^2 find a by first constraint. Again this is not a correct method as big O is different from exact time, but still it gives a rough estimate

Comment: O(n^2) can be a function like 1000000 + 0.0001(n^2). So theoretically you cannot predict the time just by order of complexity. Big O complexity is just a measure of how the time grows asymptotically as N (input size) tends to infinity.

Comment: Even if you know the average time is exactly c.n^2 you still can't answer this question, although you can say what the maximum likelihood estimator is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question includes mistaken assumptions which makes a solution impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Can't be answered.. And anybody who actually gives a *number* is wrong. Because *Time complexity* is *independent* of underlying machine architecture. That is why we *ignore* the *machine dependent* constants.

Each platform has its own overhead of doing certain operations. So, again, the answer is *not possible to say*.

Comment: "Because time complexity is independent of underlying machine architecture" does not justify the previous statement. O(n^2) does not mean cn^2, but if it did (the way many people in CS wrongly assume, or abuse notation), then we could determine c for that machine from the one data point given. It's not permanently unknowable, and it's not something we are supposed to ignore in practice.

Comment: @DouglasZare - In that case we should not try to find *actual executing time* based on *time complexity*. Just say what is the time taken..Because relating *Time complexity* or *order of growth* to actual *running time* is like asking - *Lions usually sleep for 20 hours a day.. Tell me for how much time does Alex the lion sleep every day*

Comment: The question said that the actual time was 10 seconds for an input of size 1000. It doesn't say we need to go from O(n^2) alone to an actual time for an input of size 10,000.

Comment: @DouglasZare - Then please tell me.. What will be the time taken for 10000 input size?

Comment: If you assume that the first data point was representative and that the running time is not just O(n^2) but cn^2, then increasing the input size by a factor of 10 increases the running time by a factor of 100, from 10 seconds to 1000 seconds. This is not a guarantee, but it is a sensible estimate in many situations.

Comment: @DouglasZare - Look at Peter Lawrey's answer. There are certain *conditions* in which this holds true. And can vary significantly based on certain factors..

Comment: I mentioned assumptions. Again, instead of saying that we are unable to say anything, or are wrong to try to make any predictions, we can make an educated guess.

Comment: 1000*1000 => 1,000,000 => 10sec  , so 10,000*10,000 = 100,000,000 = > 1000sec

Comment: @IsayasNega - Ok. It doesn't work that way.. Too complicated to explain.. See Peter Lawrey's answer.. You will get to know why..

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible to give a specific number while applies to all machines, you can estimate that an `O(n^2)` should be around 100x for a 10x increase in `n`

This comes with two important qualifications

- the time taken could be much less than this as the first test could include a significant amount of warm up. i.e. you might find it only takes twice as long.  It would be surprising, but it is possible.  In Java, warm is a significant factor in short tests, and it is not uncommon to see a test of 10K take far less time if you run it again.  In fact a test of 10K run multiple times could start to show times faster than the 1K run once (and the JIT kicks in, esp if the code is easily optimised)
- the time taken could be much higher, esp if some resource threshold is reached. e.g. say 1000 elements fits in cache, but 10000 elements fit in main memory.  Similarly 1000 could fit in memory but 10000 must be paged from disk. This could result in it taking much longer.

Comment: Hi Peter- a little explanation please? how longer based on the time given above?

Comment: @IsayasNega When you access data in L3 CPU cache, each access can take 10 ns, however if you access data in main memory this might take 70 ns.  This means the fact the data no longer fits into your L3 cache (as it is bigger) means it is 7x slower for ever access.  If there is 100x the number of accesses this works out to be 700x slower.

Comment: @IsayasNega similarly accessing data main memory can take 70 ns but accessing disk can take 70,000,000 ns.  Thus if the data no longer fits in main memory as it is 10x bigger, every access can be 10^6x slower.  If there are 100x the number of accesses, the program can take 10^8x longer.